# Deploying Meteor app on AWS Lambda

Tags: meteor, aws-lambda

Could one expect an easy process in deploying a Meteor app from the local development machine to AWS Lambda? and would it work fine?

Since AWS Lambda requires a stateless code, and Meteor is a stateful code, does that mean a Meteor app can not be deployed one AWS Lambda?

Is there a benifit from Lambda running a Meteor App?
Thanks

Comment: "Since AWS Lambda requires a stateless code, and Meteor is a stateful code, does that mean a Meteor app can not be deployed one AWS Lambda?" Yes that's what it means. AWS Lambda is not the type of runtime environment that Meteor was designed for. It's not going to work.

Comment: @MarkB Does that equally applies to Elastic Beanstalk, the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.design.html) under Scalability, the last paragraph says "Elastic Beanstalk applications should also be as stateless as possible,". Can I run a meteor app which needs mongodb collections on Elastic Beanstalk? if not, what is my best option in order to run the Meteor project? The web app deals with user logins and user related information processing.

Comment: @FredJ. Elastic Beanstalk can run "stateful" apps just fine, or many kinds of apps, really. What they mean by stateless is that state should be externalized to a DB, Elasticache, etc. However the app server itself can "warm up" and cache resources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but probably not a great fit. The folks [here](https://github.com/DispatchMe/meteor-lambdify) tried it and recommend aws elastic beanstalk instead.

I know folks who have had success with serverless + apollo server, not quite the same, but Meteor is moving in the direction of apollo these days...